# Inkjet Printers+lamp+unused pcb can It work?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

So suppose I have design x

Can I print design x inverted onto paper, shine a lamp on it above unused pcb and make a printed pcb?

Sorry for my ignorance

Cheers!

Comment: Why would you want to? The number of cheap, quick turn places is getting ridiculous. Don't bother. Let the professionals do it for peanuts, and enjoy a higher quality PCB, and not needing to deal with nasty chemicals.

Answer (score 1):

No this will not work, but you can use the toner transfer method to print markings that act as etch resist or even designators on a PCB - I have tried it with the transfer paper that [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/us/en/ph/pulsar/tonertransfer.html) sells and it works okay, with practice. You can use a laminator, (possibly modified to handle the thickness), or an ordinary clothes iron and some skill. The toner can come from a laser printer or a photocopy of an inkjet or laser printed page.

One caution- the kinds of solvents that remove flux **will** remove the markings in an instant.

If you search "toner transfer" you will find lots of tutorials.

Alternatively I think you can use UV sensitive PCB materials (it's possible to buy them pre-coated with resist) and expose them with printed transparency or paper (possibly saturated with oil in the latter case) and a UV exposure lamp.

None of these methods are as nice as buying PCBs online, made to order.

Comment: A toner transfer method can work with shiny paper too, the one from ads or market brochures. I was making the toner transfer with *special paper at first, but then got into it and found out that the paper needs to be shiny for the toner transfer to work. This means the cost for the paper is basically 0.

Comment: @Triak Have you tried it with color toner? It should work but I've not tried it.

Comment: I have HP1018LaserJet with black toner. I have not tried with color toner, because I do not have one. I assume it works, because it is the same thing, only in different color. Note that any shiny paper will work, I think the thinner the better. It is late now, I will post image from the paper I use tommorrow...

Comment: Just a hint about exposure lamps: Face tanners use four UV fluorescent lights identical to the ones used in semi-professional exposure units, but are much cheaper. One can build a simple unit from an old computer scanner and a face tanner. I got both for <20€ (<$20), but did not find time to assemble it together.  [As we are speaking about low-cost DIY PCBs]

Answer (score 0):

No. There are home pcb design options that use transparencies and UV sensitive PCBs, toner (Laserjet) transfer from glossy paper, and specialty paper, but your description of using Inkjet, paper, and a lamp, simply doesn't exist afaik.

Comment: Perfect that's sounds like what I'm looking for, what's the name of that prosses?